# Unwanted Display of Phone Permission in App Settings

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I've encountered an issue where my Android app displays phone permission in the app settings (Settings -> Apps -> My App -> Permissions) even though my application doesn't explicitly use these permissions through intents or any other means.

I've checked the following:

Manifest File: I ensured that these permissions are not declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Despite this check, the permissions still show up in the settings. Is there anything else I should be looking into? Could this be related to a specific Android version behavior?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please paste the permissions section of your `manifest.xml` file in your post.

Comment: @BenjyTec Updated.

Comment: Do you include any third-party libraries in your `build.gradle` file or as a jar? If those third-party libraries request such a permission, it will appear in the phone settings, even though you have not stated it in your own manifest file.

Comment: When you open manifest in Android Studio, there is a tab to show "merged manifest" that will include all entries any code that wanted to add something to the manifest. You can there right click on given entry to see which library is adding that, or even remove it (remember to test after removal, as the library may crash without those entries)